# multi dimensional string array in C#

Tags: string, multidimensional-array

I need to create a multi dimensional array of strings in C# like-

tiger elephant
pigeon lion
ant peacock

I'm unable to create. It either flags an error or throws an exception at the run time.
Please help me with it, by giving the correct syntax.

Comment: Please post your code so we can track better.

Comment: why don't you accept any ans?

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] animals = new string[]{"tiger", "elephant", "pigeon", "lion", "ant", "peacock"};
```

Comment: it is an array or strings not a multidimentional array for strings

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure I understand the question, the above doesn't appear to be a multidimensional array.

Do you simply want somthing along the lines of the below?

```
string[] animals = {"tiger", "elephant"};
```

Answer (score 1):

[LOOK AT THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
string[,] siblings = new string[2, 2] { {"Mike","Amy"}, {"Mary","Albert"} };
```

and also look for jagged array

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to create multi-dimensional string array and have it initialized:

```
string[] myStringArray = new string[] { tiger, elephant, pigeon, lion, ant, peacock};
```